# Network disconnected at startup

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10, every time I start the PC (Ci5 10Gen + 16GB RAM) the network icon in the top right looks disconnected, I need to manually reconnect it.
Any idea how to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
nmcli device set wlp2s0 autoconnect yes
```

Replace **wlp2s0** with **the name of your network interface**

Comment: Tested by 2 days and working! Thanks!